# FormsAuthenticationModule Authenticate event not firing when using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, forms-authentication, iis-7.5

We are using the HttpModule to hook in to the FormsAuthenticationModule and subscribe to the Authenticate event. When we use web forms this event fires in the module. When we are using MVC this event is not firing.

I have tried using the [Authorize] attribute on the Controllers and location in web.config (even though this isn't best practice) to try and get this event to fire but it still does not.

The event does fire when using the Cassini webserver but does not fire on IIS 7.5 or IIS Express. We are running ASP.NET MVC 2 using .NET 3.5

EDIT

The Authentication event fires when we request a .aspx or .ashx file. If we request an extensionless file or a .css or .js it does not fire either.

An new ASP.NET MVC application will fire this event for every file requested.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is Forms authentication working correctly in MVC?

Comment: @MaxToro yes. If I have already navigated to an aspx page the custom HttpHandlder will have already run and setup the forms cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our web.config was missing the **runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"** from the modules element in system.webServer. Once this was added all web requests receive the Authorisation event from FormsAuthenticationModule.

```
<system.webServer>
    ....
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    ....
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: @AmarPalsapure I would have but SO doesn't allow you to do that for a day.

Comment: hmmm I didn't know that, haven't asked question so far.

Answer (score 2):

Navigating to an aspx page does not test if forms authentication is working in MVC, you have to navigate to a route. I saw your answer and that's what I had in mind. Instead of the inefficient `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` I suggest removing the managedHandler precondition:

```
     <remove name="FormsAuthentication"/>
     <add name="FormsAuthentication" preCondition="" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule"/>

     <remove name="DefaultAuthentication"/>
     <add name="DefaultAuthentication" preCondition="" type="System.Web.Security.DefaultAuthenticationModule"/>

     <remove name="RoleManager"/>
     <add name="RoleManager" preCondition="" type="System.Web.Security.RoleManagerModule"/>

     <remove name="UrlAuthorization"/>
     <add name="UrlAuthorization" preCondition="" type="System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule"/>

     <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0"/>
     <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" preCondition="runtimeVersionv4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  Many people recommend turning runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests off but don't list these modules which are needed for most MVC sites to work

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's the best way to solve it, but I'm also using a combination of MVC and formpages and set all the authorisation in the web.config

```
<location path="[path]"> 
   <system.web>
     <authorization>
        <allow users="[username]" roles="[role]"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
   </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: I have tried this to see if it helped but it does not. It is also a security risk to configure security this way for MVC pages.

Comment: Just for personal information, which security risk would form using this method? Wonder how come it does not work for you.